# Powershell case sensitivity renaming

Tags: windows, powershell

I currently use Filebot to handle my initial naming of movies that I have personally ripped/downloaded.  When it identifies films with a source of Bluray, it labels the film:

```
Movie Title (Year) (BluRay)
```

What I would like is for a case sensitive powershell script to rename "BluRay" to "Bluray". My current script is as follows:

```
Dir | Rename-Item –NewName { $_.name –replace "BluRay","Blu" } >$null 2>&1
Dir | Rename-Item –NewName { $_.name –replace "Blu","Bluray" } >$null 2>&1
```

This works great, except I don't want it going through and renaming EVERY folder (because I use backup/sync software based off date modified), seeing as how it isn't case sensitive as well as false flagging certain movies such as:

```
Deep Blue Sea (1999) (Bluray)
```

So if I could make it case sensitive (preferred method) or exclude the word Blue, that should be efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be case sensitive, you just have to use the right operators. Most of the comparison operators have case sensitive variants, such as -ceq, -clike, -creplace, etc, etc. Adding Where-Object can make it target and change only the ones you need to:

```
Dir | Where-Object Name -cmatch 'BluRay' | Rename-Item –NewName { $_.name –creplace "BluRay","Blu" } >$null 2>&1
```

Or if you need to capture lowercase b as well for some reason:

```
Dir | Where-Object Name -cmatch '[bB]luRay' | ForEach-Object {
    $Item = Rename-Item $_.FullName -NewName ($_.Name –replace "BluRay","Blu") -PassThru
    $null = Rename-Item $Item.FullName -NewName ($Item.Name -replace 'Blu', 'Bluray')
}
```

Chris

Comment: I copied and pasted your code as is and all I received were errors.  Something along the lines of a code block.  I realized that even though my original script was going through and renaming every movie folder, it did not affect the modified date/time.  I just added an additional line to my script to catch false positives (Bluraye to Blue).  Thank you for the help though!

Comment: I've edited the example above, the script block for NewName is only valid if it's running in a single pipeline. Added PassThru for Rename-Item to capture the first step of the rename. Sorry about that.